# How to draw a chart in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, charts

I wonder Google App Engine can return a chart ?

What I want is a statistical chart, is there a way for my app in Google App Engine to create a .png chart then return it to the browser ?

For instance when I click a url such as :

http://My_App.appspot.com/Show_App_Stats

It will show me a graphic chart.

Comment: The platform has no built-in Chart API, so it's pretty much irrelevant to how you draw the chart.  You probably want something like Google Charts, although doing it yourself with some python or Java library may be your preferred solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years too late, but we now have [Matplotlib](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#matplotlib) available for Python 2.7 apps. (It's currently marked "experimental" so you shouldn't rely on it, but it is an option.)